# Core Motion with external sensor data?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion, magnetometer

I have designed a device that transmits motion data over BLE. Is there any way to subclass or otherwise use Core Motion with data that is not derived from the internal iPhone sensors?

I had a look at https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/SphereMotionTeapot

> "Device-motion data is derived from both the accelerometer and the
>   gyroscope [apparently these are in the Sphero]; Core Motion processes the data before delivering it to the
>   application."

i.e. they appear to be introducing external sensor data into Core Motion, but I am not smart enough to figure out how they are doing it.

I have BLE delegates set up to receive and present the acceleromoter, gyro and magnetometer data but can I get this into Core Motion to run it's fusion algorithms and device motion updates using this data?

Any pointers to how this might be achieved would be very useful and I will post back with any success stories.